# SQLException getting sql statement

Tags: vb.net, exception

I am working on a VB.Net application. The application sometimes throws sql exceptions. Is there a way to pull the sql statement that threw the error? If not, what is a work around?

Comment: If it is only sometimes it seems unlikely it is a syntax error in the SQL.  "SQL Exception" is very broad - you should look at the inner exception

Comment: What do you mean by "pull the sql statement"? If you mean actually view the SQL that was executed then it will be in the `CommandText` of the `SqlCommand` that was executed. That said, you should look at each item in the `Errors` collection of the exception for more specific information from the database itself.

Comment: I do not have a deep understand of exceptions or the inner workings of them. I guess what I am trying to do is to have a way to log the exceptions or view what the statements are when my application is used in the field. There are pieces of data (variables) I want to log if any exception is thrown. most of the time it is going to be sql exceptions